# How it's possible to override Dropwizard / Jetty parameters in Java for high performance?

Tags: java, rest, jetty, yaml, dropwizard

**My use case is to configure Dropwizard and / or its embedded Jetty for high volume of REST requests.**

Jetty tuning is possible for connectors (for instance). I've found that SelectChannelConnector is interesting, but official Dropwizard documentation does not mention it.

http://www.dropwizard.io/manual/configuration.html

This connector uses efficient NIO buffers with a non-blocking threading model. Jetty uses Direct NIO buffers, and allocates threads only to connections with requests.

Any suggestions about yaml or java configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`SelectChannelConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector.html) is for Jetty versions 6 thru 8.  [All of which are now EOL](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) (End of Life).

[Starting with Jetty 9](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/129583679a83651f6a53917a181693dccdee29b9), there is now a [`ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html) which is a NIO connector ([Jetty 9 dropped all BIO connectors](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/872282c34cbb2df5f824a8986885c413e4aabf72#diff-60da16158054d6889b05cd2c0f4ba91b)).

Dropwizard uses [Jetty 9 `ServerConnector`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.4/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/HttpConnectorFactory.java#L449-L475), and doesn't use the older, now EOL connector types.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I use effectively Jetty 9.

Comment: According to the documentation, server:applicationConnectors:acceptorThreads and outputBufferSize properties can be set to higher values. But, using Java Visual VM, I can see that Dropwizard acceptors threads are not running all together. It is a normal behavior?